# IntentService unique and coupled to notification

Tags: android, service, notifications, android-intentservice

My app is running an `IntentService` to download data in the background. While doing so, it sends `Notifications` to update the user about the progress.
The problem is, if the BatterySafe mode gets started, the `IntentService` gets killed, the Notifications stay there though (for example saying 30%).
Is there a way, to couple the lifecycle of the notification to the lifecycle of the service?

A second problem is, that I only want one instance of the `IntentService`. Is it possible, to achieve this?

In some Apps, for example the `Avast AntiVirus`, the background task seems connected to the notification, indicating that this background task is running. If this is a standard solution, it seems to solve my problem, so it would be great, if you could tell me the name.

Comment: did you try `@Override public void onDestroy() { super.onDestroy();  // remove notificaiton here  }`  ?

Comment: That could solve the one problem, but it doesnt solve the problem, that I just want one instance of the intent service. Thats why I hoped there is a already built in solution (especially since other apps seem to use something like this)

Comment: Services (unless you're doing some multi process stuff) are always just one instance.

Comment: I know that for normals services, but also IntentServices? It seems, like there can be more instances..

Comment: No. IntentServices extends from service, receive each 'onStartCommand' one at a time and queue them to be passed to 'onHandleIntent'. After no more commands are left, it stops. It's a pretty simple code that you can check easily with Android Studio decompiler.